# Can I send a database in a zip folder with mantaining the connection between the database and the php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, database

I want to send a folder that contains my HTML code, CSS, js and PHP. how can I include the database and keep the connection between my files and the database?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The question is a bit vague, but with most databases you can do a backup of the database while it's running. So make a script that does that backup, zip it and the move it. This won't interfere with your existing connection.